# what is the use of fs.open() in nodejs, what is difference between fs.readfile and fs.open()

Tags: node.js, filesystems, readfile

I want to know what is the use of `fs.open()` in nodejs application.

What is the difference between the `open` and `readfile` methods in nodejs, and how do they work?

Answer (score 15):

You'd call `fs.open()` if you want to perform several actions on that file. Methods like `fs.readFile()` are simply shortcuts that also prevent forgetting to close the file. (Especially less obvious cases like try/catch.) But you wouldn't want to constantly reopen and reclose the same file if you're working on it.

If you look at the documentation (http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), the first argument for `fs.read()` says fd while the first argument for `fs.readFile()` is filename. The fd stands for "file descriptor" which is the object returned by fs.open(). The filename is simply a string.

Here is an example of leveraging the `fd` for reading and writing.

```
fs.open('<directory>', 'r+', (err, fd) =>  {
// r+ is the flag that tells fd to open it in read + write mode.
// list of all flags available: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system_flags
// read using fd:https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback
// write using fd: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback
// close the flag: fs.close(fd);
});
```

Comment: So if the open means I can do several operations on the file, how can I read and write the file after opening it? I mean, if you use the readFile, then it also opens and close it on its own, so we need to somehow read the file with opening and closing it in the end

Comment: @YonatanNir Use flags and the available methods of `fd`. I have updated my answer with the same.

Comment: What's the syntax to reading or writing with open? I can't find  a legitimate working example anywhere

Answer (score 4):

With fs.open() you open the file and can then can do several things to it. Read it, write it, close it etc..
With fs.readFile without having to open or close the file you read it. Check for more information:

[Node.js FS](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback)

Answer (score 2):

Yes as stated above, if you use the fs.readFile() it will open the file for you and read the contents. You would use fs.open() if you want to do several operations or the operation is conditional.   There are several examples in w3schools.
https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp